snowflake: python connector: execute many: not able to insert
I have created a table
CREATE TABLE "VALIDATION_RULES_RESULTS" (
    id INT AUTOINCREMENT,
    created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    mongo_data_ingestion_id STRING,
    table_name STRING,
    col_name STRING,
    rule_name STRING,
    success STRING,
    element_count INT,
    missing_count INT,
    failed_records_indexes VARIANT,
    failed_records_values VARIANT
);

the below is my python script
    insert_statement = f"""
    INSERT INTO "VALIDATION_RULES_RESULTS" (
        mongo_data_ingestion_id,
        table_name,
        col_name,
        rule_name,
        success,
        element_count,
        missing_count,
        failed_records_indexes,
        failed_records_values
    ) select 
        mongo_data_ingestion_id,
        table_name,
        col_name,
        rule_name,
        success,
        element_count,
        missing_count,
        parse_json(failed_records_indexes),
        parse_json(failed_records_values)
    from VALUES (
        %(mongo_data_ingestion_id)s,
        %(table_name)s,
        %(col_name)s,
        %(rule_name)s,
        %(success)s,
        %(element_count)s,
        %(missing_count)s,
        %(failed_records_indexes)s,
        %(failed_records_values)s    
        )
    """

    # Prepare the data for executemany
    rows_to_insert = []
    for rcd in snowflake_validation_rule_row:
        row = {
            'mongo_data_ingestion_id': rcd['mongo_data_ingestion_id'],
            'table_name': rcd['table_name'],
            'col_name': rcd['col_name'],
            'rule_name': rcd['rule_name'],
            'success': str(rcd['success']).lower(),
            'element_count': rcd['element_count'],
            'missing_count': rcd['missing_count'],
            'failed_records_indexes': json.dumps(rcd['failed_records_indexes'], default=str),
            'failed_records_values': json.dumps(rcd['failed_records_values'], default=str)
        }
        rows_to_insert.append(row)

    snoflake_conn.cursor().executemany(
        insert_statement,
        rows_to_insert
    )

getting error
20:44:13.63 !!! snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 12 at position 8
20:44:13.63 !!! invalid identifier 'MONGO_DATA_INGESTION_ID'
20:44:13.63 !!! When calling: snoflake_conn.cursor().executemany(
20:44:13.63                       insert_statement,
20:44:13.63                       rows_to_insert
20:44:13.63                   )
20:44:13.63 !!! Call ended by exception

sample insert values
{'mongo_data_ingestion_id': '1728370271', 'table_name': 'yest', 'col_name': 'test', 'rule_name': 'basic_rule_expect_column_value_lengths_to_be_between', 'success': 'false', 'element_count': 10, 'missing_count': 0, 'failed_records_indexes': '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]', 'failed_records_values': '["1982-04-20 00:00:00", "1984-12-15 00:00:00", "1981-07-10 00:00:00", "1977-12-24 00:00:00", "1965-05-13 00:00:00", "1957-05-17 00:00:00", "1991-12-29 00:00:00", "1913-03-15 00:00:00", "1983-08-27 00:00:00", "1957-04-07 00:00:00"]'}


After lot of struggle i found the right syntax
insert_statement = f"""
    INSERT INTO "TEST" (
        MONGO_DATA_INGESTION_ID,
        TABLE_NAME,
        COL_NAME,
        RULE_NAME,
        SUCCESS,
        ELEMENT_COUNT,
        MISSING_COUNT,
        FAILED_RECORDS_INDEXES,
        FAILED_RECORDS_VALUES
    ) select 
        $1,
        $2,
        $3,
        $4,
        $5,
        $6,
        $7,
        PARSE_JSON($8),
        PARSE_JSON($9)
    from VALUES (
        %(mongo_data_ingestion_id)s,
        %(table_name)s,
        %(col_name)s,
        %(rule_name)s,
        %(success)s,
        %(element_count)s,
        %(missing_count)s,
        %(failed_records_indexes)s,
        %(failed_records_values)s
        )
    """

    # Prepare the data for executemany
    rows_to_insert = []
    for rcd in snowflake_validation_rule_row:
        row = {
            'mongo_data_ingestion_id': rcd['mongo_data_ingestion_id'],
            'table_name': rcd['table_name'],
            'col_name': rcd['col_name'],
            'rule_name': rcd['rule_name'],
            'success': str(rcd['success']).lower(),
            'element_count': rcd['element_count'],
            'missing_count': rcd['missing_count'],
            'failed_records_indexes': json.dumps(rcd['failed_records_indexes'], default=str),
            'failed_records_values': json.dumps(rcd['failed_records_values'], default=str)
        }
        rows_to_insert.append(row)

    snoflake_conn.cursor().executemany(
        insert_statement,
        rows_to_insert
    )


